# Changing grid label style in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, grids-graticules

In  all my maps the grid labels looks like:
[image]

I try to find a way to change it to that label style:
[image]

I work with version arcview 10.3. I seek in data frame properties-->grid-->style - but didn't found any suitable example.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Make Grids And Graticules Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/make-grids-and-graticules-layer.htm) tool that may enable you to do this:

> Creates a grouped layer of feature classes depicting grid, graticule,
>   and border features using predefined cartographic specifications. Grid
>   layers are ideal for advanced grid definitions which are scale and
>   extent specific.

I have not used this tool personally, so you may need to experiment with it.